# Running xclock immediately logs me out of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, nvidia

I have a vexing problem that has wasted most of my morning.  When I try to make an R plot, I get logged out of my machine immediately.  I tried

```
xclock
```

and the same thing happened - immediate log out.

Some details:

Graphics card:
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX Titan] (rev a1)

OS:
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, x86_64

Currently using NVIDIA proprietary driver version 340.46
(http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/78469/en-us)

I tried purging the Ubuntu graphics drivers, uninstalling NVIDIA, reinstalling NVIDIA, and rebooting, and I'm back where I started.  X seems to load fine, I can use Firefox (and play YouTube videos) with no trouble.

But God help me if I type "xclock" in the terminal.
Also, when I try and plot something in R, as in

```
plot(1:10)
```

The plot window shows briefly, then the screen goes black, and I'm sent right to the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out upgrading to Trusty Tahr and reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers solved the problem handily.